# failed to load template.html from custom angular 6 compoent

Tags: angular, angular6

I created a custom component in typescript and published to npm. 
But when i am trying to use it in my project with npm install it throws an error in browser console

```
Failed to load my-component.template.html
```

But instead of templateUrl if i directly use template it works

```
my-component.component.ts



 import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector:'my-component',
    templateUrl:'./my-component.template.html',
})

export class MyComponentComponent{
    constructor(){}
}
```

my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "my-component",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "npm run clean && tsc -p . && npm run copy:html",
    "watch": "tsc -w -p .",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "copy:html": "cpx \"src/*.html\" \"dist/src\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "copy": "^0.3.0",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/index.js",
    "dist/index.d.ts",
    "dist/src"
  ]
}
```

I am writing a script to include .html in package
[my-component source code](https://github.com/naresh217/angular6)

Comment: try to remove `./` from `templateUrl:'./my-component.template.html',`

Comment: @Hussein I tried but no luck

Comment: Any luck resolving this?

Comment: no. but you can try using `angular libraries` concept introduced in newer versions.